# Does Google Container Engine SDK/API exist?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-kubernetes-engine, google-api-python-client

I am planning to launch container cluster from an SDK/API. Presently, I am fine with any language, but I prefer NodeJS SDK. As far as I have seen, I could not find any Container engine SDK. Here is the [NodeJS SDK for GCP](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node) which does not contain container engine. In fact it contains SDK only for very few GCP services.

I came across [OAuth API](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters/create?authuser=1) for container engine but it involves human intervention to launch it. I am looking for service account based authentication for the SDK.

Are there **container engine SDKs** available ?

Update after **discussion with Robert Lacok**:

This is the code I tried to use for container APIs with API-key, it does not work. It expects Oauth 2 token, or some other credentials other than **Service account**. I tried API-key it didnt work. I dont know how to use Service account authentication with the API.

Here is my source code:

[image: code]

Here is the error:

[image: error]

I see a method for **Application Default credentials.** But I dont think so it will be useful for my use-case. I am trying to create **container cluster** from **AWS Lambda**. So, I cant use application default credentials. Is there any other options ?

Answer (score 1):

The API for Google Container Engine is very limited at the moment as all the features are in Alpha status and because they can change not many people are incorporating them into the SDKs they are developing.

These are the current available APIs: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/

And here is the Alpha APIs: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/container/

Comment: Ya I understand that many of the container features are in alpha. Sorry if this question is stupid, the above links are command-line ones right ?, So the cmd line uses the normal OAuth API right ?

Comment: also https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-overview/  and https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is making calls to the REST API and using the client library for OAuth2 authentication.

You can browse the API documentation and see that every method has a short how-to for a number of languages, NODE.JS being one of them. Have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters/create) for an example on how to create a container cluster.

You also mentioned service account authentication. The preferred way to do this is to use the application default credentials, you can have a little read [about them here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork).
In short, you want to set an environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json` which is a key to service account you generated in console.
Then the [client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) will take care of the rest (getting the OAuth tokens and what not).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer!! So, here is my thing: I do not want any human intervention for executing the REST API. In fact, I dont have a client library to do the OAuth. I want SDKs that operate only on service account. Here is the link for compute engine SDK: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node#google-compute-engine-alpha. This works with the help of service account. Having said, I did not find conatiner-engine in the above link. So, my question is does Container engine SDK for other languages like python, java exist ?

Comment: With the application default credentials you don't need any human intervention, don't worry, they're commonly used for server side applications. Have a look at the link again, the numbers are different options ordered by precedence, not steps. Number 1 doesn't need intervention and it's not necessary to perform gcloud auth application-default login. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork

Comment: Cool!! My bad!! I did not check the links properly!! So, correct me If am wrong: As of now, proper container engine SDK for nodeJS does not exist. But, the REST API for the same do exist. So, In order to use the REST API with the service account, we can use the nodeJS client https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client to achieve it. Am I right ?

Comment: Right, that's pretty much it. The SDKs are usually just nice function wrappers for the same API calls (which could for example wait for the cluster to finish creating, this way you might need to implement some create & while not ready: wait loop).

Comment: Gotcha!! Will give it a try!!

Comment: I gave it a try, I could not do it. I have updated my answer with the source code and error. If you find I am doing something wrong, let me know. Thanks in advance.